# When (and when not) to wait for completion in selenium webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Can someone explain me in detail, why "some" operations in the selenium webdriverjs need to wait for the async function to return and others do not ?

In the official sample, `driver.get('http://www.google.com')` uses no promise to wait for the completion before using `driver.findElement` but when retrieving the title `driver.getTitle()` uses a promise before comparing.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation explains what happens in the [Control Flows](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section.

**Behind the scenes, it's all promises, even when you don't need to handle them yourself.**
If you do not specifically tell WebDriverJS otherwise, there is a promise manager that handles instructions so that in *many* cases, promises are handled for you. The documentation gives this example. If you give these instructions:

```
driver.get(“http://www.google.com”);
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
  console.log(title);
});
```

The promise manager weaves them like this:

```
driver.get(“http://www.google.com”).
then(function() {
  return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
}).
then(function(q) {
  return q.sendKeys('webdriver');
}).
then(function() {
  return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG'));
}).
then(function(btnG) {
  return btnG.click();
}).
then(function() {
  return driver.getTitle();
}).
then(function(title) {
  console.log(title);
});
```

The reason you need to handle the promise returned by `getTitle` is that `console.log` is not a WebDriverJS function and thus does not participate in promise management.